# Can the keyword 'this' be used in an abstract class in Java?

Tags: java, abstract-class

I tried with below example, it is working fine.

I expected it to pick sub-class's value since object won't be created for super class (as it is abstract).  But it is picking up super class's field value only.

Please help me understand what is the concepts behind this?

```
abstract class SuperAbstract {
    private int a = 2;
    public void funA() {
        System.out.println("In SuperAbstract: this.a " + a);
    }
}

class SubClass extends SuperAbstract {
    private int a = 34;
}
```

I am calling `new SubClass.funA();`

I am expecting it to print 34, but it is printing 2.

P.S.: 
What I want to know is why using this in an abstract class not giving me an error?

As below text is emphasizing `this` would work on an instance and abstract classes won't have an instance.

> Within an instance method or a
>   constructor, this is a reference to
>   the current object — the object whose
>   method or constructor is being called.
>   You can refer to any member of the
>   current object from within an instance
>   method or a constructor by using this.
>   from: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Comment: @aioobe hey guys have you got your answer of this above question ? If yes so please can you edit this question with updated answer because I also stuck in this question.

Comment: @VikasVerma My question is about usage of this keyword in the context of abstract class, not about access modifiers.

Answer (score 31):

To answer the question in the title: **Yes**, `this` can be used in an abstract class. An abstract `Animal` is created at the same time as a `Dog` is created.

### Overriding fields

You can't override fields the way you have tried it. Fields "are not virtual" like methods.

From Java Quick Reference: [Overloading, Overriding, Runtime Types and Object Orientation - Overriding Methods](http://www.janeg.ca/scjp/overload/overridingMethods.html)

> - **fields cannot be overridden but they can be hidden** ie if you declare a field in a subclass with the same name as one in the superclass, the superclass field can only be accessed using super or the superclasses type

<sup>*If you could*, the field would probably have had to be at least protected :-)</sup>

### Creation of objects of abstract classes

> since object won't be created for super class (as it is abstract)

It *is* actually instantiated.

The `abstract` keyword only ensures that, when instantiated, it's instantiated in the form of a subclass. When instantiating a `Dog`, you're at the same time instantiating an `Animal`! The `this` reference in the context of an `Animal` will thus always refer to a `Dog` or a `Cat` or whatever, but in all cases it refers to some `Animal`. :-)

As the example below illustrates, the `this` reference makes sense even in an abstract class:

```
abstract class Animal {
    public String name;

    public Animal(String name) {
        System.out.println("Constructing an Animal");
        this.name = name;
    }

    public abstract void speak();
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    public Dog(String name) {
        super(name);
        System.out.println("  Constructing a Dog");
    }
    public void speak() {
        System.out.println("Bark! My name is " + name);
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        new Dog("Woffy").speak();
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Constructing an Animal
  Constructing a Dog
Bark! My name is Woffy
```

---

**Update:** The `this` reference refers to the same object in the super class as in the sub class.

You could try to add

```
public Animal getSuperThis() { return this; }
```

to the animal class, and do

```
System.out.println(this == getSuperThis());
```

in `Dog.speak()`. You would see that it prints true.

Comment: Thanks aioobe. So, JVM actually instantiates two separate objects (one for super class, and one for sub class) and both will be stored separate in heap. Is my understanding right?

Comment: Yes, it is printing true means both are same.  But somehow distinction between super class and sub class is being maintained by JVM. I am saying this because in my program, super class's private variable (which won't be inherited) and it's value are just there for me to access them.

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question, but private / public / protected etc are there only at compile time. These access modifiers play no role in runtime. The JVM does not make a distinction between superclass / subclass, it is just one instance.

Comment: @Reddy: What you're actually seeing is a subclass instance with a field a and a *second* hidden field a inherited from the superclass.

Comment: @aioobe: can you elaborate more? It sounds interesting.

Comment: Not sure how I can elaborate more. If the compiler does not complain about you accessing private variables where you're not allowed to, then how should the program violate this rule at runtime? It can't. Thus they don't play any role at runtime (unless you go into some reflection business) :)

Comment: @Michael, In java private members should not get inherited to sub-class. It seems that super class code will be keep in separate box (something like that) and sub class in separate box.

Comment: @aioobe: thanks, it seems likely that it might be happening that way. But, can you provide any reference? OR where can I check it in the java's source code?

Comment: @Reddy: Private members are *most definitely* inherited by subclasses. Subclass code is just not *allowed* to access them. But that is just an artificial restriction enforced by the compiler (and I think also bytecode verifier).

Comment: Thanks Michael, aioobe is saying the same. Where can I get more information on this?

Comment: @aioobe according to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564011/oop-access-modifiers-copmile-time-or-run-time

Private Public and Protected do exist in a Java binary.

Comment: @VikasVerma may be you can check that part by de-compiling the class file and see if access modifiers exist or not

Comment: @Reddy Ok i'll try but are you sure that its correct  access modifiers play no role in runtime in java ?

Comment: @Reddy If you got your answer, so can you please edit this question with updated answer ?

Comment: @VikasVerma My question is not about access modifiers. It is about usage of this keyword in the context of abstract class.

Comment: @Reddy Apparently yes and first I also didn't mention you in my comment that is related to access modifier but when you answered then I mentioned you .Indeed, I asked aioobe related to access modifier.

Answer (score 11):

Any field declared in a class is unique, even if it has the same name as a a field in a base class (i.e. only *methods* can be overridden, but not fields).  Therefore, there are two distinct fields in the derived class:  `SuperAbstract.a` and `SubClass.a`.  The fact that the base class is `abstract` has no impact.

The `abstract` keyword simply signifies that a class cannot be instantiated, i.e. you cannot write `new SuperAbstract()`.  You can only instantiate object of the subclass, which must override all methods marked `abstract`.

Comment: The fact that the field is `private` has nothing to do with it. It would be two different fields, even if the field in the super class was public.

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided contains variable `a` as private member of the `SuperAbstract` class. Since, you don't seem to override the function, it represents the code from the `SuperAbstract` class, and executing it will get access to the `a` declared in the class itself, regardless of the fact that it is being called from any inherited class. To access the value of the later variable, you need to override the function by defining the function again in the derived class. The final code looks like this:

```
abstract class SuperAbstract {
    protected int a = 2;
    public void funA() {
        System.out.println("In SuperAbstract:" + this.a);
    }
}

class SubClass extends SuperAbstract {
    private int a = 34;
    //Overriding the above function
    public void funA() {
        System.out.println("In SubClass: " + a);
        //Or even check using the super keyword
        System.out.println("In SubClass with super: " + super.a);
        //Now call the function to display the value of a from SuperAbstract
        super.funA();
    }
}
```

In the above code I changed the `a` to protected, so that it could be accessed from the derived class too.