# OOP Access Modifiers: Compile-time or Run-time

Tags: java, c++, oop, compiler-construction

I've heard that *Access Modifiers* `Public, Private and Protected` are just some Compiler Stuff, and they're not actually exists in the compiled *Binary Code*.

Now I'm wondering how much it's correct? And if it's correct, does it mean that *Encapsulation* is not exist in the binary code at run-time? So, if you modify the binary to access a `Private` method illegally, in theory, there isn't anything to check your rights, neither any OOP mechanism nor Operating System, right?

I've also tagged the question for both C++ and Java. I'm aware of the difference between them, just curious to see how different they handle *Access Modifiers*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Access modifiers are solely a compile time mechanism in C++. In Java however, they are enforced at runtime too, because Java also has a runtime typesystem, and it can dynamically (at runtime) create classes. So it needs to enforce access at runtime too for types it doesn't know about at compile time.

### Why use access modifiers?

The sole purpose of access modifiers is to enforce design.

Say you have a class `A` that you implemented

```
class A
{
public:
  void DoSomething()
  {
    // use private member mPrivMember to do something
  }
private:
  int mPrivMember;
}
```

And some code using class `A`:

```
A a_obj;
```

The above code can call `a_obj.DoSomething()`, however they don't have direct access to mPrivMember, so `a.mPrivMember` written outside class `A` will not compile.

Now, why would you want some members accessible to outside code and some not?
Well, here is why: at the moment, the method `DoSomething()` uses `mPrivMember` to actually do stuff. But after some time, you might decide you want to *refactor* the code in DoSomething, to improve it. You found a different way to *do something* that doesn't involve using `mPrivMember` anymore. So you delete `mPrivMember` and reimplement `DoSomething` some other way.

Now, if there was code outside your class using `mPrivMember`, that code wouldn't compile anymore because you have deleted `mPrivMember` when reimplementing `DoSomething`. To prevent existance of such code, you restrict access to `mPrivMember`. The mechanism to do that is through *access qualifiers* such as `private` and `protected`.

This allows you to refactor code in the future without worrying that other code might use internal members.

### Recap

`public` `private` and `protected` are compile time mechanisms in C++. They do not exist in the generated binary form of your program, and thusly such protections are not enforced. Anything is accessible from anywhere.

In Java however, classes can be created at runtime if I'm not mistaken. Which is the reason why it also has to check for access at runtime too so it can enforce them, thus `Private` `Public` and `Protected` do exist in a Java binary.

Comment: Do you think it could be helpful if we have them in binary also? Could it be useful in any case?

Comment: No, since binaries aren't supposed to be modified in that form. And a binary won't be generated if access rights are being violated in source code in the first place, because of compile time errors, so putting such enforcement mechanisms in a binary would needlessly bloat it and add overhead and be redundant.

Comment: @Mahdi note that in Java the access modifiers exist in the binary form. I have updated my answer's Recap section to explain why.

Answer (score 2):

**Please note this answer is with respect to Java** 

Both. If you try to compile code which tries to access inaccessible object or method, you'll get compile-time error:

and at run time, JVM checks the access:

You will get following exception if you try to access at run time. With improper access level java.lang.IllegalAccessError:

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, that's why I tagged both `C++` and `Java`. So, `JVM` will do the magic there? I'm thinking how `C++` will handle that! :)

Answer (score 1):

Compiled C++ code has no concept of private/protected/public. It goes down to machine code, which has no concept of those. Without native support for that, how could you support them? Better yet, how could you even make native support for that.

Access modifiers are for humans, not for machines. Access modifiers are a *design* aspect, not a security aspect.

**tl;dr**: By the time C++ code is actually running the machine has no idea private/public/protected ever existed.

Comment: I thought there might be a mechanism like an `Access Table` included in the binary, checking the rights ...

Comment: @Mahdi Nope :). It would add a huge performance hit to add something like that at that low of level. You'd basically have to do an extra lookup for *all* code. That would mean a huge performance decrease. (Also, it would literally have to be done at a hardware level. Otherwise how do you stop code from just jumping to a 'private' address? Actually, now that I think about it... I have no idea at all how you could implement true private/public/protected without different address spaces or crazy-huge lookup tables.)

Comment: oh yeah! I see what you mean! we need `OOP Processors` ... :D