# Compile time or Runtime for type casting/ type binding / type inference etc

Tags: java

I am relatively new to Java and I had an exam past year that got me stuck.

The task asked me to differentiate which options run at Compilation time / Runtime.

1. Type casting.
2. Late binding.
3. Accessibility checking.
4. Type inference.
5. Type erasure.
6. Type checking.

Are there any sources I can read to improve my understanding on static / dynamic binding?

Comment: [The Java Tutorials cover most of it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: When you ask questions like this you should provide your own attempts at answering, for comment or critique or confirmstion. This is not a homework service.

Answer (score 5):

- **Type casting** - **Compile time** but could not be catched and throw `ClassCastException` ([Java Type Casting](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-casting))
- **Late binding** - **Runtime** in general and **Compile time** for calls to final, private, or static methods ([Late Binding in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22392047))
- **Accessibility checking** - Access modifiers are solely a **compile time** mechanism in C++. In Java however, they are enforced at **runtime** too, because Java also has a runtime typesystem, and it can dynamically (at runtime) create classes. So it needs to enforce access at runtime too for types it doesn't know about at compile time. ([OOP Access Modifiers: Compile-time or Run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15564176))
- **Type inference** - **Compile time** - Type inference is a Java compiler's ability to look at each method invocation and corresponding declaration to determine the type argument (or arguments) that make the invocation applicable ([Type Inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html))
- **Type erasure** - **Compile time** - Type erasure can be explained as the process of enforcing type constraints only at compile time and discarding the element type information at runtime ([Type Erasure in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure))
- **Type checking** - **Compile time** but facilitating **runtime** type checking eg via `instanceof` ([What are the things are checked at compile time by Java?](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-things-are-checked-at-compile-time-by-Java))

Comment: Does type casting happen at Runtime as well ? 
For example if a Circle class inherits from a Shape class and there is another class named Dummy with no associations with either shape or circle. 
When i define :
Object s = new Dummy();

Shape shape = (Circle) s; 

does it still compile ?

Comment: @JiaZhengLua check the [Dynaming casting](https://blog.frankel.ch/dynamic-casting-java/) feature, this one allows doing this in context when we do not know exact type on compile time and we need to enforce check on runtime. I believe your example will not compile, and even if it would, you are going to encounter `ClassCastException`